# How to delete or edit by using 2 check boxes in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox

I am displaying a data in DataGridView object. The first column represents a delete and second is edit as check boxes, the rest is data.

What I am trying to do is to do delete and edit to the selected data when one of the check boxes are selected.

I am stuck of how to do something when one of check boxes was selected, basically how to check which field was clicked.

How do I do this?

I have this which uncheck any other field checked earlier:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dgvPC.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(ContentClick_CellContentClick);
}

void ContentClick_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPC.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[Delete1.Name].Value = false;
        row.Cells[Edit1.Name].Value = false;
    }
}
```

I am adding data as such:

```
if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) == "PC Password")
{
    // Count PC passwords.
    countPC++;

    dgvPC.Rows.Add(read.GetInt32(0), false, false, 
        security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(5), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName), 
        security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(6), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer from your statement that you are unable to identify which checkbox is being considered

So to narrow in you should attempt at using the `CellValueChanged` event of the grid

```
void grd_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
     {
          //Now you know its a checkbox
          //use the ColumnIndex of the CurrentCell and you would know which is the column
          // check the state by casting the value of the cell as boolean
     }
}
```

If you want the action to be immediate then you will have to commit the value and this happens when the focus moves out of the cell. Try handling `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` of the grid

Something like this should work for you

```
void grd_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grd.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        grd.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Comment: CellValueChanged works kind of weird. I have inserted MessageBox inside of your When I select one checkbox nothing happens but when I then select other check box then I am getting 2 message boxes.